# Undefined index when passing variable to another page

Tags: php, variables

I tried using post to pass my variable q2 to a different pages, but it keeps getting undefined index error.
Here is my code:
Page 1:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Question 2: Your age ?<br> <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="a"> 15-<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="b"> 15-25<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="c"> 25-35<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="d"> 35+<br>
</form>
<a href="page2.php">Submit</a>
```

Page 2:

```
<?php
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
Echo $q2;
?>
```

Page 2 output:

```
Notice: Undefined index: q2 in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\page2.php
```

Comment: This looks surprising... I suggest you dump the contents of `$_POST`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data isn't being POST'd, as you're simply linking to page2.php.

It needs changing to

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Question 2: Your age ?<br> <input type = "radio" name="q2" value="a"> 15-<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="b"> 15-25<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="c"> 25-35<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="d"> 35+<br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I take that comment back. In your form you are **navigating** to `page2.php`, not **submitting** the form.

The correct way would be:

```
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="d"> 35+<br>
<!-- add the submit button inside the form -->
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

And in your `page2.php`:

```
<?php
//always use isset before checking for POST variables
if(isset($_POST['submit']){
  $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
  echo $q2;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have already written in form action 

no need of this <a href="page2.php">Submit</a>

<input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
write this line before </form> tag close instead of this line 
<a href="page2.php">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code `<a href="page2.php">Submit</a>` was just a link. It's not a form submit.

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Question 2: Your age ?<br> 
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value="a"> 15-<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="b"> 15-25<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="c"> 25-35<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="d"> 35+<br>
</form>
<a href="page2.php">Submit</a>
```

In your page.php you can debug using `var_dump`. Something like the following

```
<?php
$q2 = $_POST['q2'];
var_dump($q2);
echo $q2;
?>
```

So you will got null result.

And when you try with form submit like the following

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
Question 2: Your age ?<br> 
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value="a"> 15-<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="b"> 15-25<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="c"> 25-35<br>
<input type = "radio" name="q2" value ="d"> 35+<br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

You will be got something like

`string(1) "a" a` `string(1) "b" b` `string(1) "c" c` `string(1) "d" d`